# How to force capital letters using AJAX and JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, keyup

I am new to AJAX. I would like to force Capital letters in the inputText after the keyup event. How can I do this using AJAX and JSF?

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21363541/2459449

Answer (score 2):

you can convert entered value of `<h:inputText />` in to uppercase by using `text-transform: uppercase` in `style` class.

Which will convert each `keyup` value into `Uppercase`.

**sample.xhtml:**

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel id="label" value="Enter your name : " />
    <p:inputText id="inputBox" value="" style="text-transform: uppercase"/>
</h:form>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope this helps.!!!

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use `converter`

```
    <h:inputText value="#{retailer.code}" label="#{msg.retailerId}" 
        id="retailerId" required="true" size="10" maxlength="6">
            <f:converter converterId="upperCase" />
            <f:validator validatorId="alphaNumeric-validator" />
    </h:inputText>
```

2) You can do it in backing bean (in setter)